# Swift Import Module file still causing undeclared identifier compiler error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am developing a framework in Swift, and I've run into trouble while trying to use my .swift classes inside of Obj-C files.

- I have confirmed that I am importing the correct module file: "SDK-Swift.h"
- I have **NOT** created my own -Swift.h module. I am using the one provided by the IDE
- There are no naming convention clashes for any of my classes
- The `Product Module Name` is indeed SDK
- GGNetworking inherits from `NSObject`, therefore including the necessary `@objc`

I am still given the compiler error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'GGNetworking'` even though I have done all of the steps necessary according to Apple's documentation.

The implementation and project itself couldn't be more simple.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SDK-Swift.h"

@interface GGHomie : NSObject

@end

@implementation GGHomie

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        GGNetworking *network = [[GGNetworking alloc] init]; // <-- Compiler error here
    }
    
    return self;
}

@end
```

I know I'm not the only one on SO wrestling Obj-C to Swift code ;) Can anyone weigh in on this?

## Update

SDK-Swift.h

```
// Generated by Swift version 1.0 (swift-600.0.51.4)

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
# include <uchar.h>
#elif __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted) 
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"

#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

GGNetworking.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

public class GGNetworking: NSObject {
    
    public class var baseUrl:NSString! {
        get {
            return "http://www.google.com/mobile/api/v1/"
        }
    }
    
    public class func getInImageAd(url:GGInImageAdUrl!, completionHandler:(AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url.absoluteString!).response { (request, response, data, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("An error occurred while getting an in-image ad (\(url.absoluteString)): \(error)")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            } else {
                completionHandler(data, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class func getInScreenAd(url:GGInScreenAdUrl!, completionHandler:(AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url.absoluteString!).response { (request, response, data, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("An error occurred while getting an in-screen ad (\(url.absoluteString)): \(error)")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            } else {
                completionHandler(data, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a screenshot of my Build Phases setup:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is `GGNetworking` non-private (i.e. `internal` (default) or `public`?
- Does `GGNetworking` have a non-private initializer?
- Is the initializer ObjC compatible? I.e. not using parameter types not available in ObjC.
- What is the content of your `SDK-Swift.h`? Xcode actually generates this file somewhere in your `DerivedData` folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...`). Just let Finder search for it.
- Pasting relevant code for the `GGNetworking` class could also help us.
- Is that Swift file actually compiled? I.e. can you use it from other Swift files?

*Updated after more info provided:*

Does adding `public override init() { super.init() }` to `GGNetworking` solve the issue?

Comment: This should get like 50+ point! The public initializer was it for me.